# How to pass variable to dynamic SQL statement's SELECT list within a DB2 stored procedure?

Tags: db2-400

I created DB2-400 stored procedure with a declared variables EFFDT Varchar(10). The value for this variable is supposed to be passed to a SQL statement within the same stored procedure.  The procedure compiles fine, but when I execute the procedure, I get

> SQL-0206 error "Column or global variable @EFFDT not found".

Here is the code:

```
BEGIN 
-- Variable used to replace effective in SQL below with 1st 
-- day of current month as text in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format

DECLARE     EFFDT VARCHAR(10);

SET EFFDT = VARCHAR_FORMAT(MONTH(CURRENT DATE) || '/01/' || YEAR(CURRENT DATE),'MM/DD/YYYY') ;  -- First day of current month


    ...

--SQL STATEMENT
CREATE TABLE INFOMATICS.TEMP_CHGS_2_ADDS AS 
  (SELECT FNAME, MI, LNAME, MAILING_ZIP,
          SPECLTY, SPECLTY_DESC, @EFFDT AS EFF_DATE 
     FROM INFOMATICS.TEMP_CHGS) WITH DATA;

    ...
End;
```

I expect to see

```
John M Smith 1111 GD General Dentist 05/01/2019
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I tried changing “@EFFDT” to EFFDT to match the declared variable name, but I got back the error message SQL0312 - EFFDT not defined or not usable. Similarly, I tried changing both the declared variable name and it’s reference in the SQL statement  “@EFFDT”. Again I got back the same SQL0312 error message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `@EFFDT` is not defined either as a declare, or as a parameter. I see where you are declaring `EFFDT` though. Maybe try changing `@EFFDT` to `EFFDT`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the variable. Instead I wrote an SQL UPDATE statement to modify the effective date (EFF_DATE) to the 1st day of the current month.  Here’s the SQL UPDATE statement:
UPDATE INFOMATICS.TEMP_CHGS SET EFF_DATE = VARCHAR_FORMAT(MONTH(CURRENT DATE) || ‘/01/‘ || YEAR(CURRENT DATE),’MM/DD/YYYY’);

The EFF_DATE value returned was as expected ‘05/01/2019’.